# Regex javascript + replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text, replace

I got few lines like these:

```
/coc59409.p?id=1218405784092
/acme-made-skinny-lray-orange/5616664.p?id=1218679205878
/incase-campus-brk-gray-pink-berry/7209107.p?id=1218833962192&skuId=7209107
```

and I need to delete in all of them what come after this ".p?id="
how can I do that?

results :

> /coc59409.p?id=
>
> /acme-made-skinny-lray-orange/5616664.p?id=
>
> /incase-campus-brk-gray-pink-berry/7209107.p?id=

Comment: Did you try using the `.replace` function?

Comment: What have your tried? Also, do you also want to delete the `&skuId=7209107` as well?

Comment: Hint: This doesn't need any regex.

Comment: what expected output for your sample?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression here - contextually what you are referring to is the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of the *URL* and there are already tools in the *DOM* with the facility to tokenise this, for example:

```js
var url = '/coc59409.p?id=1218405784092',
    a   = document.createElement('a');

a.href = url;
console.log( a.pathname ); // '/coc59409.p'
```

Details about the [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).

Answer (score 0):

```
=> "/coc59409.p?id=1218405784092".replace(/\?.*$/,"")
>> "/coc59409.p"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split it,

```
var url = '/acme-made-skinny-lray-orange/5616664.p?id=1218679205878'
var urlArr = url.split('=');
console.log(urlArr[0]+'=');
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Take each line and replace `id=[THE REST OF THE LINE]` with `id=`.

Like so:

```
"coc59409.p?id=1218405784092".replace(/id=(.*)$/, 'id=')
```